# Concatenate strings with quotation marks separated by commas

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation

I want to write a function that concatenates multiple strings into one one string, but each part is marked with quotation marks and separated by a comma.

The function should basically take the inputs `"a"`and `"b"` and print this `c('"a", "b"')`, which will result in an output like this:

```
c('"a", "b"')

# [1] "\"a\", \"b\""
```

How can I created this `c('"a", "b"')` in a function body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by a single `paste0()`:

```r
x <- c("a", "b", "c")

paste0('"', x, '"', collapse = ", ")

# [1] "\"a\", \"b\", \"c\""
```

or `sprintf()` + `toString()`:

```r
toString(sprintf('"%s"', x))
# [1] "\"a\", \"b\", \"c\""
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
x <- c("a", "b")
out <- paste0("c(", paste0('"', x, '"', collapse=", "), ")")
out
#> [1] "c(\"a\", \"b\")"
eval(parse(text=out))
#> [1] "a" "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With `dQuote`:

```r
v <- c("a", "b", "c")
toString(dQuote(v, q = ""))
#[1] "\"a\", \"b\", \"c\""
```